# How to save an audio file with speech recognition(chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

> I have a requirement to include the speech recognition for text boxes
>   in web surveys. But we have another requirement to save the recognized
>   audio into server along with this. I have implemented following below
>   code for recognition and I am not sure how to start with recording the
>   recognized file.

```
<center><span id="button"  class="click" onclick="listen()">Start Recording</span></center>


<script src="[% GraphicsPath() %]platform.js"></script>
<script src="[% GraphicsPath() %]webspeech.js"></script>
<script>
    var speaker = new RobotSpeaker();
    var listener = new AudioListener();
    function talk() {
        speaker.speak("en", document.getElementById("openend_text").value);
    }

    function listen() {
    $("#button").html("Started Recording..");
        listener.listen("en", function(text) {  
            document.getElementById("[% QuestionName() %]").value = document.getElementById("[% QuestionName() %]").value+" "+text;
        $("#button").html("Start Recording");
        });
    }

</script>
```